# untar files into single directory preserving the directory structure

Tags: tar

It is possible, and if so how, to use tar to extract a zip while preserving the directory structure? Currently it just extracts everything into a single directory using the path as the file name.

Example file name
Farlex.581429F59E1D8_1.5.1.9_neutral__wyegy4e46y996.main\Assets\buttons\add.png

Comment: What do you mean by "use tar to extract a zip while preserving the directory structure"? Do you mean that the file names actually contain backslashes and tar in your platform doesn't create a directory tree?

Comment: platform does not create a directory tree

Comment: Maybe its a problem with the file itself rather than the platform but still: what is your platform?

Comment: platform is OSX. the file is an app from microsoft that mac can not open natively. My main issue is in production the servers run a different version of tar that saves the directory tree but my local machine does not.